# Is there an alternative open source software for connecting to wireless networks for WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, software-rec, wireless-networking, wpa

Is there an alternative open source software for connecting to wireless networks, other than the one built into windows xp?

Comment: so you know most wireless cards will come with their own connection utility that replaces the Windows wireless utility.  As for the reason WHY you need an open-source solution... (?)

Comment: @l0c0b0x Yes, but the Windows software isn't that good and the Vendor-specific utilities are often even worse.  Even when the vendor utilities are not worse, it's a training issue teaching users about a different program every time you refresh a set of machines.  This is a good question and I at least am also interested in the answer.

Comment: But why open-source?

Comment: open source is free and more actively developed. the question why open source vs proprietary software is a entirely different question.

Answer (score 1):

Though not an open-source application Avanquest does offer a free connection manager application. I've never used it, but it certainly looks like ti would fit the bill.

http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/avanquest-connection-manager-107347